# Rails - no method error for new form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm sure that there is a simple solution to this problem, but I can't for the life of me see what I am doing wrong - it's been a few months since I've worked on a Rails project, I must be forgetting something important.

I'm just trying to create a basic Rails form, but I am getting a `no method` path error when I navigate to the new form page.

This is for my Report model...

routes.rb

```
resources :report, only: [:new, :create], path_names: {new: ''}
```

report_controller.rb

```
def new
    @report = Report.new
end
```

report/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @report do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

Navigating to http://localhost:3000/report yields

```
undefined method `reports_path'
```

Just to be comprehensive, here's the model...

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :weather
    belongs_to :feature
end
```

and the routes

```
report_index POST   /report(.:format)      report#create
new_report GET    /report(.:format)        report#new
```

I'm sure this is an amateur mistake... but I can't see what it is!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your routes to include a `:show` path if you want to be able to go to `/report`.

The path that I believe you are looking for is `localhost:3000/reports/new`

Comment: With this `path_names: {new: ''}` I map the new report action to the /report url.  If I take that out and go to http://localhost:3000/report/new, it's the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Oh for the love of god.  It was a pluralization issue.  The files should appear and be named as follows:

routes.rb

```
resources :reports, only: [:new, :create], path_names: {new: ''}
```

reports_controller.rb

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @report = Report.new
    end
end
```

And the view files should all be in a folder called 'reports', not 'report'.  The model is just the singular report.rb.